# getMonth returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript, date, gitlab-ci

I have some tests that test the getMonth method on my code.

For everything to go well, I set my date to UTC 0, if I put for example `Date.UTC(new Date (2021, 0, 1))` I have a string `2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

But when I upload it to gitlab and it passes the tests there, the result is `2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` too, but `getMonth()` give me `12` value.

Can you help me please?

The following example returns on my tests `1` but `12` on gitLab terminal.

```
console.log(
    "original time month__ ",
    new Date(
       new Date(year, month - 1, 1).getTime() -
          new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
    ).getMonth() + 1
);
```

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see what's going on... See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `Date.UTC(new Date (2021, 0, 1))` returns `NaN`. You probably need `getUTCMonth`

Comment: Maybe when I call `new Date()` again, is putting back the local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using [`getUTCMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) instead of `getMonth` for UTC

Look at the console screenshot for explanation. *(Testing from India +05:30)*

[image]

```js
let demo = new Date('2021-12-31T20:00:00.000Z'); //TZ: +05:30
console.log('getMonth(): ', demo.getMonth());
console.log('getUTCMonth(): ', demo.getUTCMonth());
```